# Join a table with Already Joined table based on

Tags: sql, join

I am thinking of joining a table with already joined table based on the 'Policy-numbers'. I am using SQL server.

The First part of query is as follows :

```
     select
            MPolicyNumber,
            SNumber,
            IName,
            EDate,
            NewRenewal,
            GPremiumUSD,
            Status,
            deductibleinUSD
    from IT.dbo.Blended
    where deductibleinUSD > 0 and ProductLine in ('Health','Cas')
    order by EDate
```

I want to join the above table with the following table based on Policy numbers that is matching between the first and second query

Second Query:

```
    select a.[Policy Number], 
    a.[LOB], 
    a.[Primary_R Amount]as Bound_deductibles,
    a.[Primary_R Type],  
    a.[Effective Date] as CAS_EDate
    from IT.dbo.BOUND_TAB a
    inner join IT.dbo.RATER_OF_RECORD b
    on a.idxFile = b.[Bound Rater]
    order by [Policy Number], [idxFile] desc
```

Thanks in Advance for the help!

Comment: Why don't you simply modify the 1st query so it joins to the appropriate tables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This ought to do it (without making any changes to syntax preference or efficiency)

```
select c.MPolicyNumber, c.SNumber, c.IName, c.EDate, c.NewRenewal, c.GPremiumUSD,
       c.Status, b.deductibleinUSD, t.*
from IT.dbo.Blended c inner join
  (
    select a.[Policy_Number], a.[LOB], a.[Primary_R Amount]as Bound_deductibles,
           a.[Primary_R Type],  a.[Effective Date] as CAS_EDate
    from IT.dbo.BOUND_TAB a inner join 
         IT.dbo.RATER_OF_RECORD b on a.idxFile = b.[Bound Rater]
  ) t ON t.Policy_Number = c.MPolicyNumber
where c.deductibleinUSD > 0 and c.ProductLine in ('Health','Cas')
order by c.EDate
```

Comment: This approach worked as I expected, except the addressing columns is incorrect.. Thank you so much..

Comment: I am also trying to filter the records if EITHER the 'Blended' table  showed a deductibleUSD > 0 or if the 'Bound Tab' that it did. I tried adding the a.[Primary_R Amount] > 0 in the inner joins, but it just unions all. Any thoughts or ideas on this ? Thanks in Advance

Comment: So, to make sure I understand correctly, you added "where a.[Primary_R Amount] > 0" to the inner query and the results weren't what you expected?

Comment: "where (c.deductivleInUSD > 0 OR t.Bound_deductibles > 0)"

Is this what you are looking for? I was unclear on the field you are looking at from the "BOUND_TAB" table, but it should be pretty easy to change if my assumption was incorrect.

There are some efficiency gains to be had here, but I am just trying to keep the answer concise and simple.

Comment: I was trying to to compare c.deductivleInUSD with a.Bound_deductibles. This actually shows error .

Comment: If I understand you correctly, that you are trying to reference the alias "a" outside the parentheses for "t", you can't do that.  To compare the results from the inner query with the outer query in the where clause, you must use "t" which is the inner query results alias.